# Sorting on a calculated field with X++

Tags: methods, axapta, x++

I am a long time developer in MS Access but Now I need to develop in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009.

I have a report that uses a method on the body of a report that calculates an "exp book date". Now I am being asked to sort on this field.
I am guessing I need to move the method to the query, in order to make the field able to be sorted.
But when I copy the method to the Method level of the query, it say that the field does not exist. Which it doesn't. How do i get the feild to be visiable?

```
display utcDatetime Test()
{
    real            AddDays;
    utcDatetime     CDate;
    ;

    AddDays = smmQuotationPrognosisGroup::find(smmOpportunityTable_1.PrognosisId, false).PrognosisDays;

    CDate = smmOpportunityTable::find(smmOpportunityTable_1.OpportunityId, false).createdDateTime;

    return DateTimeUtil::addDays(CDate, AddDays);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it is not possible to sort directly by a display method.
Yet there are some workarounds, e.g.:

- Use a temporary table with a field which is filled by your display method's logic before you run the report and then use this temporary table in your query.
- Override the report's fetch method so that you have full control over
  fetching the data via X++.

Depending on your report's size these actions can take some time.

Comment: Also in simple cases, you can make a view then a computed field: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg845841.aspx.
This may require knowledge of SQL functions.